# Cannot import twisted's internet module

Tags: python, namespaces, package, twisted

Am getting the below error when executing python protocols/smpp/test/test_post_upgrade.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "protocols/smpp/test/test_post_upgrade.py", line 1, in <module>
    from protocols.smpp.proto import *
  File "/tmp/Wass/protocols/smpp/proto.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import defer, reactor
ImportError: No module named internet
```

Here's my tree:

```
/tmp/Wass$ tree
.
├── __init__.py
└── protocols
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    └── smpp
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __init__.pyc
        ├── proto.py
        ├── proto.pyc
        └── test
            ├── __init__.py
            └── test_post_upgrade.py

3 directories, 10 files
```

Here's the content of the principal files:

```
/tmp/Wass$ cat protocols/smpp/proto.py
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor

/tmp/Wass$ cat protocols/smpp/test/test_post_upgrade.py 
from protocols.smpp.proto import *

/tmp/Wass$ cat protocols/smpp/__init__.py
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

For information, i can resolve this issue by one of these actions:

- Emptying `protocols/smpp/__init__.py`, but this is usefull for the whole project so i can just empty this file, my project will no more run ..
- Renaming `protocols/smpp` to anything else, for example `protocols/toto` will work (with changing `protocols/smpp/test/test_post_upgrade.py` to `from protocols.toto.proto import *`

The second solution is so confusing as i dont have any `smpp/proto.py` in my system that can cause a conflict ...

Here's a simpler representation of the issue:

```
Wass/
Wass/__init__.py
Wass/protocols/
Wass/protocols/smpp/
Wass/protocols/smpp/__init__.py
Wass/protocols/smpp/test/
Wass/protocols/smpp/test/__init__.py
Wass/protocols/__init__.py

Wass/protocols/smpp/test/test_post_upgrade.py:
> from Wass.protocols.smpp.proto import SMPPClientProtocol

Wass/protocols/smpp/proto.py
> from twisted.internet import defer, reactor
>
> class SMPPClientProtocol:
>     pass
```

Execution outcome:

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
:/opt/smpp.twisted/:/opt/smpp.pdu/:/tmp/Wass/
python /tmp/Wass/protocols/smpp/test/test_post_upgrade.py
> Returns the same problem above
```

Comment: What is the output of "python -c 'import twisted; print twisted.__file__'"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of potential issues here.

1. Is `Wass` really supposed to be a package, or is it an entry on `sys.path`?  If it's really a package, you should be adding `/tmp` to your `PYTHONPATH`; if it's a path entry, you should be adding `/tmp/Wass` to `PYTHONPATH`, and deleting `/tmp/Wass/__init__.py*`.
2. Don't run `python` on modules within a hierarchy directly.  It confuses the issue.
3. If `Wass` is going to continue to be a package (i.e. contain an `__init__.py`), you should adjust your imports to be `from Wass.protocols.smpp.proto import ...`.
4. Don't use `import *`.  It's just confusing; someone reading your code has no idea what names are supposed to come from what module.
5. Try to simplify this as much as possible, and upload a [complete, runnable example](http://sscce.org/) of a set of files that causes the problem.  Since I don't know what's inside those .py files, I have to guess at the cause.

Ultimately I think that the problem you're seeing is caused by the combination of a top-level module named `protocols`, which conflicts with several modules within Twisted, and the use of `import *` which is probably pulling in another name like `basic` or `smtp` or `pop3` into that namespace and clashing with something, then the magic of namespace packages combines with it all to create an explosion.  I can't be more specific than that without seeing the actual code that triggers the problem :).

Whenever faced with an issue like this though, it's good to take a step back and make sure that the working directory, the script directory, and PYTHONPATH are all separated out so you know exactly how your code is being imported.  Specifically, I'd recommend doing something like this:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir runstuff
$ cd runstuff
$ PYTHONPATH=/tmp/Wass trial protocols
```

Hopefully that will work out better for you.

Comment: I've updated the question since commenting doesnt support formating (as it seems ..)

Comment: thank you for your guidance ! in fact, print twisted.__file__ pointed me that it's conflicting import. It was resolved by absolute_import